# How to solve Deadlock in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I identified a read query with a pessimistic Lock on Table X.
There is also another read query on the same Table X which runs in a Transaction.
We are using JPA and Hibernate. So I need to solve the following Issue.

In the log there is this error Message:

> org.hibernate.sql.exec.ExecutionException: A problem occurred in the
> SQL executor : Error advancing (next) ResultSet position [Transaction
> (Process ID 236) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer
> resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock
> victim. Rerun the transaction.]

I hope there is this one solution.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only solution is to prevent the deadlock - maybe look into why you have a read query issuing a pessimistic lock on Table X and avoid it. Most JPA applications are recommended to use optimistic locking instead of pessimistic locking to allow more concurrency. In the end though, two threads updating the same resource will cause issues - you can make one wait for the other with pessimistic locking (and risk deadlocks and delays), detect conflicts afterward with optimistic locking, or just ignore the issue and allow stale overwrites.